# Outgoing Routing in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm reading Pro ASP.NET MVC 3.0 from Appress.Chapter 11 is about URLs routing system.
In passing extra variables from outgoing section is explained about getting segment values from url
for example for bellowing routing :

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{color}/{page}");
```

if a user is currently at the URL /Catalog/List/Purple/123, and we render a link as
follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click me", "List", "Catalog", new {page=789}, null)
```

The routing system will match against the route and It will generate the
following HTML:

```
<a href="/Catalog/List/Purple/789">Click me</a>
```

But when i use this code for the following example it generates:

```
 <a href="/Catalog/List/Purple/">Click me</a>
```

i don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving that route mapping above the other route mappings in your global.asax file

Comment: Actually i use this example in ASP.NET MVC internet sample with some changes (Home and Index instead of Catalog and List)  and it produces odd urls for example  In Home page, About url is Home/Index/purple Also i have only one rout and Html.Actionlinks for "About" doesn't provide color varialbe  @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { color=purple, page = 10 }, null)
          -----
          @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new {page=789}, null) i expected that it projects "Home/About/Purple/10" for "About" instead of "Home/Index/Purple" in Home page

Comment: Have you tried the Route Debugger? You'll be able to see exactly what url is hitting what route in order to distinguish where your problem is, try it: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx